# Ubuntu 22.04 unexpected shutdown

Tags: 22.04, shutdown

I am using a Lenovo Thinkcentre mini desktop. I upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. Now, once a week, sometimes twice a week, the computer completely shuts down unexpectedly. Naturally, it happens when I am in the middle of some important business.

Based on a suggestion, I ran the following command:

```
journalctl -b -1 -g 'systemd' -r --no-pager | head -n200 > shutdown.txt
```

and I have the file.

Comment: You "have the file"? Please post it or at least relevant parts?

Comment: I'm not able to post it - too long; it is 49 lines. Is there a way to upload the file?

Comment: If it's a desktop, it's  probably heat related. The way I would go is make sure cpu fan in turning.  Make sure all other fans are turning. Vacuum the dust globs, if any, out of the chassis.

Comment: Make sure you have 4 inches clearance all around the PC. Vacuum external air inlets from the outside. Check all power connections for good insertion. Look for and connector pegs that pushed out the back of a connector.

Comment: Open the chassis, remove the heat sink/fan from the cpu. Have some arctic silver 5 on hand. Examine the thermal interface material on the cpu. Is it dry and crusty. Is it thick. In any case, use 99.9% isopropyl alcohol and paper towels to clean   the cpu and cooler.

Comment: Get them really clean. If the cooler is not flat where is mates the cpu, take a piece of 600 grit silicon carbide wet/dry sandpaper wet, on a flat surface. Glide the cooler on the wet paper. Rinse paper every five minutes. Make sure you're sanding it flat. When it's improved---not perfect--just improved, get your arctic silver 5 out. Wipe the cpu with alcohol, and the cooler on its mating surface. Don't let them touch anything. With the as5, make 2 lines dividing the processor in thirds.

Comment: They should be less than 1/8" wide, and a bit more than 1/8" from the edges of the processor.  Don't use more. If you make a mess, clean it up and try again. Apply cpu and mounting arms with screws, or whatever they give you. Once the  cooler is in place,, tight, turn in back and forth a tiny tiny bit to spread the thermal interface compound. One note, if the stock cooler is lame-ass, buy a good one for $20-$30 off eBay.

Comment: If you have a video card, with fan cooling, take it apart and clean it. Remove the cooler from the gpu. Wash it oout

Comment: Do the saame with the cpu cooler, unless you buy a good one. Clean the fan enclosure, fan blades. Don't break a fan blade. Use cotton swabs. Clean the gpu and cooler mating surfaces. Put proportionally equal amount of AS5 on gpu, mate the surfaces, and put the screws back.put one screw in part way, then the diaglnal part way. Then the other 2 part way. Tighten them each a couple turns until they're snug.

Comment: Twist the gpu cooler to spread the thermal paste. Put the cover back on. Take your 600 grit paper and lightly sand the contacts on the video card, until you can some shine come through. Don't touch anything but the contacts. And don't keep on until they're all perfectly shiny.  Just until some shine comes through. Wipe contacts with paper towel. Insert video adapter.

Comment: Shake the chassis and listen for loose items, like screws. Test your power supply, testers $12.00 on eBay. That job would require 1.5 hours.

Comment: @Brian This thread of comments might be getting too long to read. You could edit your answer or post another one

Answer (score 0):

Go into power settings and turn off `auto suspend`, make `power button`to `shutdown` Turn off hibernation. Hold down the power button until the machine shuts completely off, 10 seconds or so.

Remove the AC adapter and battery. Push the power button once a second for 30 seconds. Let the laptop sit without power connected for 1/2 hour. Put the battery and AC adapter back on.

Press power. Quickly start alternating between pressing F1 and F2, about once per second. The UEFI setup will appear.

In the UEFI set up, disable all apm, all PCIe power management.  secure boot, set compatibility mode to on, set operating system to `other os`, and save and exit.

Log in to Linux. Press the power button until the machine shuts down completely. Start the machine again, and the problem should be gone.

You can set your power settings the way they were, one setting at a time per week. If the problem comes back, the last setting you changed is the problem.

Laptops have a chip that overrides all operating system settings, so things critical to the machine, like adequate cooling, don't fail because of an OS setting. That chip holds the suspend and hibernation states. By pressing the power key without shutting down the OS, the suspend and hibernation states are cleared.

Removing all power sources, and pressing the power button 30 times discharges the capacitors on the motherboard, which normally hold enough electric charge to power low-level functions. So, that step completely clears all settings in volitile memory.

This gives you a clean slate. But the first time you boot bqck into Linux, some of the settings can be restored by the OS. Pressing and holding the power button until complete shutdown gets rid of those potential problems.

When you start the machine again, you have a clean slate. This procedure solves at least half of all problems with Lenovo laptops.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response. I did try to follow the instructions; however, this is a desktop and it didn't seem that much applied to me.